# HTML5 audio does not work on Opera and Safari?

Tags: html, ubuntu, html5-audio

HTML5 audio does not seem to work on Firefox and Opera:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

You can test it from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all).

Any ideas why and how to make it cross browsers?

I am on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Please , which operative system you use ?

Comment: @NikolaLukic im on Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646130/no-sound-with-html5-video-player-under-firefox-or-chromium-with-ubuntu-gnome-15) fixes my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be from the browsers you are using. Try updating  or downloading the latest browser program from your provider.

Comment: try restricting the browser to let users know the problem. and recommend them to use the browsers that the audio will work fine.

Comment: Make your answer to be comment , in this way your A will be - flag .